# Inner contents of text node plus an attribute

Tags: t-sql, xquery

I hope it's plain to see what I want to accomplish here. I've been experimenting a little back and forth.

```
insert into @description
select 
d.value('*[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') text
,d.value('../@id', 'varchar(50)') parent 
from @xml.nodes('//*[local-name(.)="description"]') as xtbl(d)
```

I want to query all the elements of name description, record the inner text and a reference to the parent node.

The above runs but text is all NULL. (Edit)

XML exerpt:

```
<effort id="6d9cb0d1-58b0-11e2-acbb-00268315c2c5" start="2013-01-07 10:55:55" status="1" stop="2013-01-07 11:10:34">
      <description>
          Stängde sajten med felmeddelande.
      </description>
 </effort>
```

Table def:

```
declare @description  table(
    text varchar(MAX)
    ,parent varchar(50)
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have no SQL server here, but `//*[local-name(.)="description"]` is bad syntax. `*:description` does the same and is much nicer to read. Also, I guess you can't go up to the parent in d.value, so you might want to select `//*:effort` instead and then user as `d.value()` parameters `@id` and `description/text()` instead.

Comment: That being said, your question is missing what is currently going wrong. So does it not work as expected (if so, whats the actual result?) or do you get any error message?

Comment: Of course. I'll edit my question and then try your syntax. Thanks.

Comment: So your suggestions feel promising but I get: XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *' This stuff is just not my forte.

Comment: Works with `description[1]`. @dirkk, why don't you put your stuff in an answer and I'll pick it.